# Determine the order of Testing in a Project?

Tags: techniques, manual-testing

When QA teams receive a software build, how do they normally test? Given is the random list of test techniques.... arrange them in order:

1. Re-testing
2. Smoke testing
3. Regression testing
4. Sanity testing
5. Functional testing

Comment: You should take a look at your papers...

Comment: sounds like a homework/class assignment

Answer (score 6):

There are too many factors to be taken into account before selecting the correct testing sequence and sometime not all of the tests you have listed are really needed.

Anyhow, let's imagine the worst case when your QA team receives a new  build ready to be tested, I would follow the sequence below:

1. Smoke testing
2. Sanity testing (to be skipped when the software is not stable enough)
3. Regression testing
4. Functional testing

I think the following link could help you to clarify your doubt: http://www.guru99.com/smoke-sanity-testing.html

Answer (score 4):

Know your product.

Do you have a lot of regression problems? Do regression first.
Do you have frequent technical break-ups? Do smoke testing first.
It's the opposite : your application is very stable, so it's important to focus on the new features : Do Functional testing first.

The rationale is to go for the low-hanging fruit, which is different on each tree. Minimize your effort for finding the maximum of bugs as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.Always start with Smoke testing it will helpful to determine your new software build is fit to go for next level of testing.

2.Continue with Sanity testing it will helpful to covers the bugs which raised in smoke testing.

3. Do Functional testing and regression testing